# Ms-access Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression '(Quantity * UnitPrice) ExtendedPrice'

Tags: c#, sql, ms-access

```
OleDbConn.ole = "SELECT ProductCode, Description, Quantity, UnitPrice, (Quantity * UnitPrice) ExtendedPrice FROM SalesReturnItem sri INNER JOIN Product p ON p.ProductNo = sri.ProductID WHERE Sri.InvoiceNo = " 
+ invoiceNo + " ORDER BY Description ";
```

Whenever i excute this query i get the following error-

> Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression '(Quantity *
>   UnitPrice) ExtendedPrice'.

please help

Comment: Show us the SQL query alone.

Comment: its solved  anwser below

Answer (score 1):

Use AS - SQL aliases are used to give a table, or a column in a table, a temporary name.

```
OleDbConn.ole = "SELECT ProductCode, Description, Quantity, UnitPrice, (Quantity * UnitPrice) AS ExtendedPrice FROM SalesReturnItem sri INNER JOIN Product p ON p.ProductNo = sri.ProductID WHERE Sri.InvoiceNo = " 
+ invoiceNo + " ORDER BY Description ";
```